# git see entire merge diff

Tags: git

I want to be able to see the entire patch applied by a merge as a single diff output. In bzr this is the standard (such that if you view the diff at a merge point you get the entire diff resulting from that merge). In git I don't see how to get this unified view of the merge. Using gitk I have to click on each individual commit in the branch. I want to see the entire branch as a single commit.

I know that I can simply manually find the branch point and do a diff between two points, but this is error prone. How can I see the entire diff for a merge?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Lets say your merge has the hash "1234abc". What you can do is to run:

```
git diff 1234abc^1 1234abc
```

Pretty much displays a "before" "after" comparison.

Comment: That works. Now, if only it weren't so hard to copy the hash value from gitk.

Comment: well in the worst case just tag the version and use that tag for the comparison and once you're done, remove the tag again.

Comment: I  cannot reference the previous commit by `1234abc^1`, `1234abc~1` worked for me. My git version is 2.2.1

Comment: that is genius... i've been trying to do this... seems straight forward...hey i have a merge commit..show me what happened during it... but no...they have to make it difficult :(   Thank you for this response